# Autosizing UICollectionView cell embedded in UITableView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have spent a few day's now trying out things suggested on various SO posts but have not been able to figure this out.  I'm probably looking right at the issue!

I am making a switch over from Android to iOS and seem to be having some trouble with autolayout.  Specifically, getting the UICollectionView to resize to the height of its content.  Each collection view can have a different cell size based on its content but the cell size will be the same for each item on a given row.

The UICollectionView is nested inside a UITableViewCell.  The UITableViewCells appear to be resizing to its content height correctly and looking at the Debug View Hierarrchy the issue seems to be the UICollectionView.

I have created a mini demo and put it on this github (link below). I have thrown in a bunch of test data so the bottom part of the ViewController VC is a bit messy.  The demo just illistrates how each row can have different content size.  There can be several table rows of the same style.

NOTE: I had to add the following line to CategoryRowCell.swift in order for me to get the below screen shots.  Without this line the UICollectionView height becomes 0!

```
...
collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250)
...
```

[GitHub link](https://github.com/TehRaab/Autosizing-TableView-CollectionView)

So here is what it looks like right now..

[image: Initial screen]

scrolled down

[image: scrolled]

Notice the gaps at the top and bottom of the horizontal lists.  Here is what i am expecting..

[image: Expected Layout]

Here is part of the debug view hierarchy.  You will see that the collection view already has top and bottom margins (good), but the red lines show the excess height being applied to the collection view.  The green line indicates the height i am expecting.  I am wanted the collection view to have a height of its content.

[image: Debug View Hierarchy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to do it the other way around, having the UICollectionView as the parent and UITableView as the child. Since the first is more flexible and customizable.

Anyway for your case I think you need to take a look at two things:

1- To have a better control of the cell size you can use this func for UICollectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { 

  // The desired size based on the value at that row (the name for example)

  if objects[indexPath.row].name == "some condition" {
    return CGSize(width: 150, height: 50)
  }
  else {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 75)
  }


}
```

2- The size inspector values for the UICollectionView and UITableView (you might have some extra spacing in one of them)

[image: UICollectuinView]
[image: UITableView]

Comment: I was under the impression that UITableView was only vertically scrollable?  As for your two suggestions, i had previously tried to use that sizeForItemAtIndexPath method but it had no effect given that i want the height to be dynamic.  Also, all items in the table view are created pro grammatically and so do not have that size inspector.

Comment: sizeForItemAtIndexPath is actually useful when the height is dynamic, just have your conditions in the function and return the size based on that. I updated the answer with some code.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  This was actually going to be my fallback solution.  I was hoping that there was a solution that detects the content size automatically and size the collection views height based on the content.  I am guessing there is no off the shelf solution to do this!?

Comment: As far as I know there is no straight forward solution, but you can use the UICollectionViewFlowLayout to achieve this as well (helpful article: https://medium.com/@andrea.toso/uicollectionviewcell-dynamic-height-swift-b099b28ddd23)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have gone with hard-coding the values based on content type in the sizeForItemAtIndexPath.  May come back to this though at a later date to see if there is a "dynamic" solution.