# How do you implement a dynamically sized UICollectionView inside of a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

We have a `UICollectionView` inside of a `UITableViewCell`. The `UITableViewCell` has a vertical `stackView` with a `UIView` on top and the `collectionView` on the bottom.

From some other answers we've found, we've subclassed `UICollectionView`:

```
class DynamicCollectionView: UICollectionView {
override func reloadData() {
    super.reloadData()
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
}
```

As a proof of concept, in the *tableView*, we're setting `tableViewCell.collectionViewCellCount = indexPath.row`

We have an observer on the `tableViewCell`'s `collectionViewCellCount`:

```
    var collectionViewCellCount = 0 {
    didSet {
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

All of the breakpoints run when set on the `collectionView`'s subclassed methods.

Again, for proof of concept, we're setting the `collectionViewCell` size like this:

```
        if let layout = imageCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
```

The `collectionView` is never given an explicit height.

***Our problem is:***

The cells are only sizing properly when scrolled. Initially, the `collectionView` is not shown in the `stackView`.

We're working on getting some screen shots and a gif up, but wanted to put the question out there.

Happy to clarify more any way we can!

***Update:***

The problem seems to be happening because the `collectionView` doesn't have an explicit height constraint. `cellForItemAt...` is only called either if there is an explicit height constraint, or on scroll. However, adding an explicit height constraint doesn't get overridden with the content size.

Comment: If i get it right, you want to display full collectionView content inside tableView cell? I think you can resize your table cell.

Comment: help me understand your scenario. please

Comment: @JayrajVala Yup, you're right, I want to display the full collectionView content inside a tableViewCell. How else can I clarify?

Comment: Maybe you can check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000840/autosizing-uicollectionview-cell-embedded-in-uitableview-not-working/55005485#55005485

Comment: @ArielSD Then you can calculate table cell size. (top + bottom padding of collection inside table cell + (collection cell size * collection row count)).

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that your reloadData within the UICollectionView is getting called (sounds like it, if that breakpoint is being hit)? If it only sizes properly on scrolling, my guess is it has to do with reusable cells.

What if you try to force the cells to redisplay by sending all collection cells a needsUpdate? I wouldn't think that would be necessary because of the reloadData, but maybe something like this right after your reloadData could help you narrow down what's happening:

```
        for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
                 cell.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea...Unfortunately, it didn't work. It does seem like it has to do with something getting called when a cell is reused that isn't called originally.